# how do I prevent scheduling more than once of a cron task

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cron4j

I am using cron4j under tomcat.
I start the scheduling inside a servlet

```
doGet(){
  ...
  S.start();
  ...
}
```

How would I prevent initiating this cron task more than once, even if I call accidentally to this servlet again?

Comment: Don't execute the code in doGet() then. Do it in the servlet's init() method or some other code path that only happens once (eg spring startup)

Comment: ok, so the constructor of the servlet is running only when I start tomcat, or the first time I call the servlet? and then won't be called any-more until a new restart of tomcat happens?

Comment: See my edit. Probably best to use the Servlet.init() method instead. Or you could use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). If you're using spring, it's probably best to configure it in the ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

As commented previously, it is best to use either `ServletContextListener` or `Servlet.init()` methods for one-time initialization codes. However, if you want an answer, how to do that from `doGet()` only once, then declare and instance variable called `int counter=0` in the servlet. on first invocation of `doGet()` increment this `counter=1`. Check the counter value and don't init again if it is >0. You can use a synchronized block to increment the value or declare it as volatile to make it more fancy.